# Best way to structure classes with identical methods but different member types

Tags: c++, inheritance

Looking for some advice about how to improve the code below to maximize re-use.
Class A has a matrix member which is used in several methods. Class B is identical to class A (the methods are straight copy-paste) but the matrix member is different and is of a different type.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { set_matrix(); };
    double operator()() { // uses method1 and method2 };
protected:
    Matrix_Type_A matrix;
    void set_matrix();
    double method1() { // uses matrix };
    double method2() { // uses matrix };
}

class B 
{ 
public:
    B() { set_matrix(); };
    double operator()() { // uses method1 and method2 };
protected:
    Matrix_Type_B matrix;
    void set_matrix();
    double method1() { // uses matrix. Identical to method1 in class A };
    double method2() { // uses matrix. Identical to method2 in class A };
}
```

Ideally I'd like to re-use the class methods, where the underlying code works for both matrix types.

My initial thought was to create a child class that has a new member *matrix*, but I don't think this will work because the inherited methods still point to the base class variable, not the derived variable. E.g. something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { set_matrix(); };

protected:
    Matrix_Type_A matrix;
    void set_matrix();
    double method1() { // uses matrix };
    double method2() { // uses matrix };
}

class B : class A
{ 
private:
    Matrix_Type_B matrix;
    void set_matrix();
}
```

Alternatively, was thinking that I could use a general base class containing the methods, and then have inherited class A and class B each with a different matrix member. Problem is, the base class won't compile because the methods refer to a member that only exists in the derived class.

Any advice / ideas on how to structure this much appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Template solution seems to work. I've implemented the following

```
template <class T> class A
{
public:
    A() { set_matrix(); };

protected:
    T matrix;
    virtual void set_matrix() = 0;
    double method1() { // uses matrix };
    double method2() { // uses matrix };
}

class B : class A<Matrix_Type_A>
{ 
public:
    B() { set_matrix(); };
private:
    void set_matrix();
};

class C : class A<Matrix_Type_B>
{ 
public:
    C() { set_matrix(); };
private:
    void set_matrix();
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a template class.

Comment: Avoid to call virtual method in constructor, you may use specialization instead of inheritance, and then use alias: `using B = A<Matrix_Type_A>;`.

Answer (score 1):

How do you ensure that `Matrix_Type_A` and `Matrix_Type_B` have the same methods? If they're both subclasses of a common parent which declares the shared functionality (or if you can make them share a parent like this), just declare your `matrix` variable to be of that parent type.

If not, you could make a template class:

```
template<class Matrix>
class C
{
    ...
protected:
    Matrix matrix;
    ...
}
```

and use `C<Matrix_Type_A>` or `C<Matrix_Type_B>` as your classes.